# How to use an IP address to send mail usind sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I am doing some testing with sendmail on my linux mail server. 
I currently have 2 user accounts (excluding root) on the one server and wish to send emails from one to the other using the server IP address instead of localhost.

```
e.g.
[mary@mailserver]$ mail -s "Hello World" john@192.168.0.1
```

But when ever I try this I get a dead.letter reply, effectively saying the mail could not be delivered.

I tryed changing a few setting in sendmail.mc (sorry can't remember which ones), rebuild it and restarted the sendmail service. I also added the server IP address to the sendmail db, rebuilt it and restarted the sendmail service. Neither of which seemed to help. 
I'm very unfamiliar with sendmail so any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP adresses are not allowed by the RFC specification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The RFC is certianly the preferred method, but does it mean it's permanently set that way in sendmail or is it possible to change that setting in the config file or somewhere like that? I need to use the ip address for testing purposes.

Comment: You could try adding it to /etc/hosts

Comment: That's not correct.  See rfc2822 Section 3.4.1 Addr-Spec specification, and http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/258934-Email-address-with-IP-address-instead-of-domain-name for comments about it.  The format is user@[xx.xx.xxx.]  (note square brackets).

Comment: @NickColeman thanks for the correct answer, It works! I suggest to post this as a separate answer